# What is the correlation between the level of education and number of friends?

Tags: educational-psychology, correlation, social

I have heard, that a study was performed, maybe in Brazil, and it showed that a correlation was found – more educated people have less friends. I was unable to google this work. Maybe somebody here knows it?

I found only this study:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/293045439_Country_roads_take_me_home_to_my_friends_How_intelligence_population_density_and_friendship_affect_modern_happiness

Here the authors studied double correlations and found, that among people with very high IQ, those who have more friends are less happy than those who have a small amount of friends; among people with low IQ, the trend is opposite (those who have more friends are less happy).

It’s a pity that this study do not pay attention to the level of education – I think it is a more important descriptor, than the IQ. Have any such studies been made?

Comment: Not to be nit-picky, but you might want to proof-read the assertions as they appear to be the same.